# I have to manually add array values after split on img tag

Tags: php, arrays

I got articles that I split on the first image tag, so I can put the image in a container-fluid (full width of the page instead of a standard bootstrap format). This works fine, except when I add more images, the array is further split, and so just having $article[0] (introtext) $article[1] (full width image) and $article[2] (rest of the text) is not enough. Since the next image and text are in value 3 and 4.

How can I make sure all the following data after the first split stays inside value 2? Or maybe automatically check how long the array is and add those values dynamically?

My code now:

```
// Product \\ Content
$content    = "SELECT * FROM `lb_content` WHERE alias = '".$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['alias'])."' ";
$contentcon = $conn->query($content);
$contenti   = array();
while ($contenti[] = $contentcon->fetch_array());

$introtext = $contenti[0]['introtext'];
preg_match_all('/(<img[^>]+\>)/i', $introtext, $artikelimages);
$artikelimages = $artikelimages[0];
$splitartikel = preg_split('/(<img[^>]+\>)/i', $introtext, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

echo $splitartikel[0];

echo $splitartikel[1]; (inside container fluid but ill just add the relevant code)

echo $splitartikel[2];
```

Now when there is another image, I have to add:

```
echo $splitartikel[3];
echo $splitartikel[4];
```

manually. For the new image and text after that image.

Comment: Use 1 instead of -1 in preg_split. That is the limit value.

Comment: @karacsi_maci Thanks it shows everything now but my first image is not full width anymore. Only my first div is filled (with everything) and the rest of the divs are empty. Including the div with container-fluid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After echoing the first two pieces, join the rest of the array (if any) and echo the result:

`echo implode(array_slice($splitartikel,2));`

Comment: Didn't know `implode` could work without a glue string. You sir just taught me something.

Comment: @roberto06 Glad to help. With no parameter but the array, '' becomes the glue string.